# Set OnClickListener For Each Table Row

Tags: android, onclicklistener, tablelayout, tablerow

I have source code that use json to get data from server and show it dynamically in table. I want to make every data in row table clickable. And When data clicked, It will show new activity that contain detail of data.
This is my code :

```
for (Iterator i = penyakit.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

        Penyakit p = (Penyakit) i.next();

        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        String nomor = String.valueOf(no);
        isikolom1 = new TextView(this);
        isikolom1.setText(nomor);
        isikolom1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        isikolom1.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        isikolom1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 0);
        Ll.addView(isikolom1, params);
        tr.addView((View) Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        TextView isikolom2 = new TextView(this);
        isikolom2.setText(p.getNama());
        isikolom2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        isikolom2.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        isikolom2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        idp = p.getId();
        isikolom2.setClickable(true);
        isikolom2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        detail_penyakit.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_id, idp);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);

        Ll.addView(isikolom2, params);
        tr.addView((View) Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        no = no + 1;
    }
```

When I click TableRow it show new activity with detail of LAST Data. Not detail from data in Table Row That I Clicked. How can I show detail of data in Table Row That I Clicked? Thank You For suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the  variable `idp` you use is defined outside the iterator so, after executing the iterator, the value of `idp` will be `id` of last vlaue of `penyakit`.
So create local variable `idp` inside the iterator

Comment: When I Create Local Variable idp (Not Final), It show error.

Comment: Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must be declared final.
Any local variable used but not declared in an inner class must be definitely assigned (§16) before the body of the inner class.

Comment: try by making the variable final and assign the value while declaring

Comment: I set variable final, and yet it just store LAST Id. Not each id and when loop it not change to the next id like I want.

Comment: did you create the final variable inside the iterator, can you please post complete code

Comment: OMG!! Thankyou :D . My mistake, I make final variable in top, not inside the iterator as you said. Thankyou very much :D